# What is the main function of xp_cmdshell in SQL Server and what are its related security issues?

Tags: sql-injection, injection

I was researching on Injection issues in MS SQL Server. I came to read about xp_cmdshell. I think this must be enabled in the SQL server for attackers to perform many exploits. Actually what is this function doing and why attackers always keep an eye on this?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(v=SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows to run commands from the SQL shell provided by MS SQL Server. Meaning you can pass commands to be executed by the operating system. Attackers use these to gain complete access to the underlying operating system, rather than just the database and its data.

Comment: Is there a way to limit access to this function?

Comment: I think that by default it's switched off and only SA has access  to it (which should never be used to run queries).

Comment: "compete access" is a bit of an overstatement: xp_cmdshell runs in the security context of (at best) the service account used by the DB server process. While you definitely *could* run it as SYSTEM, it is actually recommended to use a separate service accounts with more limited rights. Getting access to xp_cmdshell is still a big issue but not automatically a root compromise.

Comment: From SQL server 2005, it is disabled by default. But you can enable this manually @raz